# Open multiple modal dialogs inside one page with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to open multiple dialogs using *Twitter Bootstrap 3*.

How can I do it? Can it be done at all?

Comment: Explain your question in detail.What you tried?

Comment: I haven't found any reference about it, so I've turned to SO.

Comment: Do you want to open multiple modal when you click a single button?

Comment: Nope i have a dynamically create list of links.

Comment: Then what's wrong? you can create multiple modal with different ids and attach this to your dynamic links.

Comment: I have reached that after I've asked you :D

Comment: @devo dude it's still a modal-dialog that means that only one can be pressed at this moment, how to disable that? And please write down your answer, that I will be able to set it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create some modals which you want like this.

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Then from your dynamic link switch to your modal using id to link href. Otherwise use onclick javascript event.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Or (the following option is better for you)

```
<a href="javascript:void(null);" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="launch_modal('your_id');">Launch Modal</a>
```

And from javascript,

```
<script>
  function launch_modal(id) {
     // Hide all modals using class if required.
     $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('#'+id).modal('show');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to have **one** this html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" title="Close">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And **many** jquery like this to add content:

```
$('#modal .modal-header .modal-title').html('<strong>:)</strong> Success!');
$('#modal .modal-body').html('<p>Something success!.</p>');
$('#modal .modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close">Close</button>');
$('#modal').modal('show');
```